# Нужно подключить БД MySQL к Excel

Tags: sql, база-данных, excel

Не получается подключить БД MySQL к Excel. Выдает такую ошибку: connection attempt failed. authentication method caching_sha2_password not supported by any of the available plugins. Пробовала создавать нового пользователя с типом аутентификации sha256 password, но проблема все равно не исчезла. Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: `ALTER USER 'username'@'host' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`

Comment: Если стоит mysql 8 версии, то и коннектор ODBC надо ставить 8 версии